# Numpy read big-endian data: data type format

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read data from a file with big-endian coding using NumPy `fromfile` function. 
According to the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) i figured that

- `">u2"` - big-endian unsigned word
- `"<u2"` - little-endian unsigned word

I made a test file to check this:

```
$ echo -ne '\xfe\xdc\xba\x98\x76\x54\x32\x10' > file
```

However, I now get the opposite result of what I expected.

For example:

```
from numpy import *
import sys

print sys.byteorder

with open('file', 'rb') as fh:
    a=fromfile(fh, dtype='>u2', count=2, sep='')

print a
for i in a:
    print hex(i)
```

gives output:

```
little
[65244 47768]
0xfedc
0xba98
```

showing that I am on a little-endian system (the first line of output). However, I try to read data as big-endian. Should't I then get

```
0xdcfe
0x98ba
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you should not:

Let's see hexdump of file

```
$ hexdump -C file
00000000  fe dc ba 98 76 54 32 10
```

Then look at the picture from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and you'll realize that your output is correct.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roman! From the link you give, I see that I confused the type of system I am using with big-endian..